# How to show isotropy of $SU(2)$ Yang Mills stress energy tensor?

Tags: special-relativity, yang-mills, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

When I vary the action of the YM Lagrangian density $$L = -\frac{1}{4} F^a_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}_a + J_a^\mu A^a_\mu$$ with respect to the metric, I obtain:

$$T_{\mu \nu} = \frac{-2}{\sqrt{|g|}} \frac{\partial}{\partial g^{\mu \nu}} \left( \sqrt{|g|} L \right) = \frac{1}{4} g_{\mu \nu} F^a_{\sigma \alpha} g^{\alpha \beta} F^a_{\beta \rho} g^{\rho \sigma} - F^a_{\mu \alpha} g^{\alpha \beta} F^a_{\beta \nu} ,$$

where $$F^a_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu A^a_\nu - \partial_\nu A^a_\mu +f^a_{jk} A^j_\mu A^k_\nu. $$

$f^a_{jk}$ being the [structure constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_constants) that embodies the properties of the symmetry group under consideration, here $SU(2)$ so that the index $a$ can run over three different values.

My question is, how do I go about showing that this stress energy tensor is invariant under rotations? I was able to show this for the $U(1)$ case with a scalar field, where I got $$T'_{\mu \nu} = R_{\mu i} R_{\nu j} T_{ij} = T_{\mu \nu}$$ using the [FLRW metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) in its cartesian coordinate form, and assuming that the time component of the scalar field was zero and $A^a_i = \phi(t) \delta^a_i$ so that the terms arising from taking its derivative only yield diagonal elements. Note that the rotation matrix used was a standard 4 by 4 matrix with 1 as its (1,1) element and sine/cosine on the remaining 3 by 3 block.

Can I do something similar for the above tensor, that is, use the same rotation matrix?